# how to open 30 MB html files in web-browser?

Tags: html, browser

My program generates an html file which is almost 30 MB, how can I open it in web-browser? I cannot open it in Google-Chrome, IE.
Thank you!

Comment: An HTML file should not be anywhere near that size. What is causing your HTML file to be so large?

Comment: My html file is a map, and I add may markers on it.

Comment: I plot a lot of lines on the map.

Comment: If the HTML file size cannot be reduced, is this question related with coding/programming?